# How do the javac command line flags CLASSPATH and -d work in the script below?

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

Can anybody tell me the meaning of the batch file code below? I know the meaning of the first line as it sets the path to current Framework directory but I need the meaning of second and third line.

> cd /d %~dp0Framework
>   **SET CLASSPATH=..\Framework*;..\Framework.;..\Framework\lib*;**
>   **javac -d . *.java**
>   pause

Comment: 2nd line - set the classpath.3rd line - compile java file

Comment: 2nd line takes 3 paths, why 3 paths and regarding to 3rd line javac *.java is enough to complie all files but they kept -d in between them why.

Comment: Because they felt like it. `-d` sets the destination and `.` is the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

> SET CLASSPATH=..\Framework*;..\Framework.;..\Framework\lib*;

tells `javac`where to find the classes you need (depend on)

The `-d .` sets the destination directory for compiled classes to the **current directory**. Please note that there is a `.` after `-d`. A `.` on command line means current directory (or what is called working directory in DOS). If you put in say `-d c:\tmp` (you might have to try `c:\\tmp` - I am not too familiar with DOS) and you actually have such a directory, the output will go there.

Hope that helps.

Comment: can you please provide an other example regarding 3rd line, because -d sets the destination but as per the code they are given the code as  **javac -d . *.java**    . so i was little bit confusing in which directory the class files stored.

Comment: First of all, does your command run as you give it? And secondly, where does javac put class fies if the command works? That will help me answer it better.

Comment: yes, my commands works fine and it gives output in the library ../framework/com/java

Answer (score 2):

In the Second Line you are setting the path of your class File. While in the third line you are using the JDK provided javac(java Compiler) to compile your java file in class files. which can be run by the jre the `-d` option tells javac the existing  directory where class files should be generated . But `javac -d . *.java` will give that it is not the correct way to use javac

Comment: can you please provide an other example regarding 3rd line, because -d sets the destination but as per the code they are given the code as **javac -d . *.java** . so i was little bit confusing in which directory the class files stored.

Answer (score 1):

I think the batch file is broken. The second line uses an undocumented way of specifying a wildcard that immediately follows a name (`..\Framework*`). See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#A1100762 for the legal ways of specifying a wildcard. Perhaps it should be `..\Framework\*`? As for the third line, the option `-d .` does nothing, because the current directory would be used by default if that option was not there.